# http4k - Need to deploy as WAR file and cannot figure out how to init servlet

Tags: kotlin, http4k

I'm using http4k and generating a WAR file with Maven. No problem.

My question is how do I initialize the servlet so it will deploy properly?

I'm used to creating a Java class that extends Servlet and pointing the web container to that with either a web.xml or a @Servlet annotation.

What do I do to use the `app.getServlet()` after I create my app and make the web container deploy that as the servlet?

This is how I'm testing with embedded Jetty - I just can't find the glue to take the instantiated servlet and tell the conatiner to serve it:

```
fun main() {
    ... snip ...
    val printingApp: HttpHandler = DebuggingFilters.PrintRequest().then(app)
    val server = printingApp.asServer(SunHttp(9000)).start()
    println("Server started on " + server.port())
}
```

I've looked in the example apps in GH for `.asServlet()` and can't find an example, and the docs here are not helpful for my use case: https://www.http4k.org/guide/howto/use_a_server_backend/

Answer (score -1):

There are adapters for Servlets in both the old and new (jarkarta) servlet flavours. It's literally a case of calling `asServlet()` or constructing HttpHandlerServlet passing your HttpHandler to it.

Check out:

https://github.com/http4k/http4k/tree/9d2863e5e55eaf65ba546877be94b3224a2ab721/http4k-core/src/main/kotlin/org/http4k/servlet

Edit: You can add a class which extends HttpServlet and construct your app manually in the init method?

```
class MyServlet : HttpServlet() {
    private lateinit var adapter: Http4kJakartaServletAdapter)
    
    override fun init(config: ServletConfig) {
        super.init(config)
       adapter =  Http4kJakartaServletAdapter(<YourHandlerHere>)
    }

    override fun service(req: HttpServletRequest, resp: HttpServletResponse) = adapter.handle(req, resp)
}
```

Comment: It's not really just a case of calling `asServlet()` - I need to somehow tell the servlet container that this is the servlet - typically I do that by having a class annotated with @Servlet or pointing to said class that extends HttpServlet in web.xml

Comment: I can get an instance of a servlet in my app by calling `.asServlet()` but it's not in the web server context and will not be served.